# How to compress/encode length of the string and decode it again

Tags: android, kotlin, logic, decode, encode

I have a string which has length of above 25 characters. now I need to compress the length of the text below 10 characters. the compression should be like encoding so that I should able to decode the text again. is there any way to do that.

I tried **base64** encoding. which encodes my string but the length goes too big. I want the length to be less than 10.

*My expected result*

> *My string = "012#MynameisIrfan#6379#hi#msg"* (**my string length 28**)
>
> *output need to be : "iryhThhdY"* (**encoded and length is less than 10**)

**After decoding** : iryhThhdY

**Result** : 012#MynameisIrfan#6379#hi#msg

Is this possible to do

Comment: You can do this only if you are using a subset of characters. What characters may appear in your String?

Comment: if your `String` can contain ANY character then this is impossible

Comment: Of course it won't be possible for any string size. But it might work for some not too long strings. Do you have more assumptions on the input string?